# Apache 2 error: not found, but the cgi-script executes

Tags: apache

I am trying to configure an Apache web server on Ubuntu, however, I get the following error:

```
[cgi:error] AH01215: .../cgi-bin/handler: 85: [[: not found: .../cgi-bin/handler
```

The cgi-script, which is not found by Apache, is present on the server, and the error is shown in the *error.log* after I make a page call handled by `.../cgi-bin/handler` and weirdly the cgi-script returns a valid HTML page (an exception, shown when a requested directory is not present)

What could be the issue? How can a cgi-script be executed and in the same time "not found"?

(I don't think it is a permission issue, as I copied the project structure with all permissions from the old server, where it worked without problems)

Comment: If you're sure the path exists and permissions/ownership are correct, maybe context? Or selinux?

Comment: It sounds like a path issue.

Comment: Hmm, but it is located exactly where Apache says it is not found